# How can I close the surplus of tabs that prevents me from closing them

Tags: chrome-for-android, motorola-moto-g, android-12, browser-tabs

I have so many tabs open in Chrome that I have been literally unable to close them, and my browser has been rendered largely useless.   HELP!

The central problem is that the focus bounces from tab to tab so fast that I can not stay on any one tab long enough to close it. In addition the "three dots" menu in the upper right, which I believe is supposed to have a "close all tabs" button, does only on rare occasions. I do not know what determines if this button is present or how to get it back when it is not. I'd accept an answer to any one of these questions), except: not 1) if there is no way to navigate to the "close all tabs" button.

1. Is there a map somewhere that shows which Chrome controls are available under what circumstances, so I can navigate
   to the "close all tabs" button?
2. Is there a way to freeze tabs in place, so that the focus changes only when I select a different tab? This is what I want most, because I would like to be able to open a tab and look at it, and sometimes save some info., before deciding if I want to close it.
3. Is there a way to make the "close all tabs" button appear when it is not on the three dots menu?
4. If there is no easy way to solve this with native Chrome, is there an app that would let me do so? If it does not provide a way to freeze the tabs in place, it has to work even though the focus is bouncing rapidly from tab to tab.
   I'm on a Moto G with Stylus 5G running Android 12, with security updates to August 2022

Thanks! I look forward to hearing from you.
}
--andrewH

Answer (score 1):

How about just killing all the tabs via adb using the command:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.chrome
```

Use adb by plugging the tablet/phone into a PC and using CMD.EXE (Windows PC) to issue the command from the folder you unzipped the [Android SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) to.  Hopefully you have USB debugging enabled on your device, you may get a prompt upon plugging your phone into your PC that you may use to enable USB Debugging. To make sure adb is running issue the command:

```
adb devices
```

Which will show your device, if not you may need your phone/tablet' drivers and install them through device manager.

The use of `adb shell` allows you to run the specified shell command on your device, `am` is activity manager, `force-stop` is the command and that's followed by the app you want to stop

Answer (score 0):

Use [Tasker](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/) and create a task using [AutoInput](https://joaoapps.com/autoinput/) that will perform the tab closing for you.

The task could be configured to close all tabs, close the current tab, close  x tabs, etc.  You could trigger it from an icon, or even using your voice once you were familiar with the tools.

Please note there may be very  small costs for these apps but they are entirely worth it.

**Tasker**
Tasker is an application for Android which performs tasks (sets of actions) based on contexts (application, time, date, location, event, gesture) in user-defined profiles or in clickable or timer home screen widgets.

**AutoInput**
AutoInput enables you to interact with any Android app automatically.

**UI Query**
Feature of AutoInput that allows you to query another app's screen for whatever it's showing, (buttons, text fields etc).